# AS3 - Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference at supportForce/general()

Tags: actionscript-3

```
package 
{

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;


    public class supportForce extends MovieClip
    {
        private var Player1Child:Player1Actual = new Player1Actual();
        private var Player2Child:Player2Actual = new Player2Actual();
        private var GreenLightLeft:Projectile1 = new Projectile1();
        private var GreenLightRight:Projectile2 = new Projectile2();
        private var _keyDownStatus:Object = {};
        private var defaultSpeed:Number = 10;
        private var Player1Lock:Boolean = false;
        private var Player2Lock:Boolean = false;
        private var Player1Left:Boolean = false;
        private var Player2Left:Boolean = true;
        private var greenLightLeft:Boolean = true;
        private var Player1CD:Number = 0;
        private var Player1Ready:Boolean = true;
        private var Player1Hit:Boolean = false;
        public function supportForce()
        {
            this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, general);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onDown);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onUp);
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, keyCheck);
            btnStart.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickStart);
            btnAbout.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickAbout);
            btnDust.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickDust);
        }
        private function general(event:Event)
        {
            if (Player1Child.BladeInstance.hitTestObject(Player2Child))
            {
                if (Player1Left == true)
                {
                    Player2Child.x -=  defaultSpeed;

                }
                if (Player1Left == false)
                {
                    Player2Child.x +=  defaultSpeed;

                }
            }
            if (Player1Ready == false)
            {
                Player1CD -=  1;
            }
            if (Player1CD <= 0)
            {
                Player1Ready = true;
            }
            if (Player1Child.x <= 0)
            {
                Player1Child.x = 0;
            }
            if (Player1Child.x >= 550)
            {
                Player1Child.x = 550;
            }
            if (Player1Child.y >= (400 - Player1Child.height))
            {
                Player1Child.y = 400 - Player1Child.height;
            }
            if (Player1Child.y <= 0)
            {
                Player1Child.y = 0;
            }
            if (Player2Child.x <= Player2Child.width)
            {
                Player2Child.x = Player2Child.width;
            }
            if (Player2Child.x >= 550)
            {
                Player2Child.x = 550;
            }
            if (Player2Child.y >= (400 - Player2Child.height))
            {
                Player2Child.y = 400 - Player2Child.height;
            }
            if (Player2Child.y <= 0)
            {
                Player2Child.y = 0;
            }
        }
        private function onUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            _keyDownStatus[e.keyCode] = false;
        }
        private function onDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            _keyDownStatus[e.keyCode] = true;
        }
        private function keyCheck(event:Event)
        {
            if (_keyDownStatus[37])
            {
                if (Player1Left == false)
                {
                    Player1Left = true;
                    Player1Child.rotation +=  180;
                    Player1Child.y += (Player1Child.height - 5);
                    Player1Child.x +=  Player1Child.width;
                }
                Player1Child.x -=  defaultSpeed;
            }
            if (_keyDownStatus[39])
            {
                if (Player1Left == true)
                {
                    Player1Left = false;
                    Player1Child.rotation +=  180;
                    Player1Child.y -= (Player1Child.height - 5);
                    Player1Child.x -=  Player1Child.width;
                }
                Player1Child.x +=  defaultSpeed;
            }
            if (_keyDownStatus[38])
            {
                Player1Child.y -=  defaultSpeed;
            }
            if (_keyDownStatus[40])
            {
                Player1Child.y +=  defaultSpeed;
            }
            if (_keyDownStatus[96] && Player1Ready == true)
            {
                Player1Ready = false;
                Player1CD = 8;
                Player1Child.play();
            }
            if (_keyDownStatus[65])
            {
                if (Player2Left == false)
                {
                    Player2Left = true;
                    Player2Child.rotation -=  180;
                    Player2Child.y -= (Player2Child.height - 5);
                    Player2Child.x -=  Player2Child.width;
                }
                Player2Child.x -=  defaultSpeed;
            }
            if (_keyDownStatus[68])
            {
                if (Player2Left == true)
                {
                    Player2Left = false;
                    Player2Child.rotation +=  180;
                    Player2Child.y += (Player2Child.height - 5);
                    Player2Child.x +=  Player2Child.width;
                }
                Player2Child.x +=  defaultSpeed;
            }
            if (_keyDownStatus[87])
            {
                Player2Child.y -=  defaultSpeed;
            }
            if (_keyDownStatus[83])
            {
                Player2Child.y +=  defaultSpeed;
            }
            if (_keyDownStatus[90])
            {
                if (Player2Left == true)
                {
                    stage.addChild(GreenLightLeft);
                    GreenLightLeft.x = Player2Child.x;
                    GreenLightLeft.y = Player2Child.y;
                    greenLightLeft = true;
                }
                if (Player2Child == false)
                {
                    stage.addChild(GreenLightRight);
                    GreenLightRight.x = (Player2Child.x - Player2Child.width);
                    GreenLightRight.y = (Player2Child.y - Player2Child.height);
                    greenLightLeft = false;
                }
            }
        }
        private function clickStart(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            gotoAndStop(2);
        }
        private function clickAbout(event:MouseEvent):void
        {

        }
        private function clickDust(event:MouseEvent):void
        {

        }
    }

}
```

The first Frame has the intro to the file like Start, etc and Frame 2 has a MovieClip Instance called Player1Child and inside the MovieClip is another MovieClip called BladeInstance. When I run it, it gives Error #1009 in the output box and the error( I guess) is in the "general" function.
You can download the actual .fla file with the .as file at https://www.mediafire.com/folder/i93zm31p7513m/A_Game.
If you can, please suggest another simpler method for the "turning" part of the two MovieClips(it already works pretty well though). Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: By the way the logic is mine haha. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I Figured it out, I Think?
Well I got it to run without any errors.

In Organised.fla  go into your symbol 'Player1Actual'

on your layer 'Blade' you will notice frame 1 is empty. (This is were the error occurs) its trying to find 'BladeInstance' on frame 1 of your symbol 'Player1Actual'.

I found a very simple solution is to just copy your symbol 'BladePlayer1' to frame 1 on layer 'Blade'.

Make sure that 'BladePlayer1' on frame 1 still has an Instance name of 'BladeInstance'
Then just set frame 1's 'BladePlayer1' Alpha to 0.

That fixed the error for me.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works at last!

Answer (score 0):

Error #1009 is commonly known as a `Null Pointer Exception.`

It means you're trying to access a property with a "." (dot) of a null or undefined variable.

you will need to figure out what the undefined variable is.

eg. look for which line the error occurs on.
maybe use `trace("var: "var);` etc.

There are heaps on this topic on stackoverflow just search

`Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference at`
and you should find how to fix.

also check out https://forums.adobe.com/message/4641806

Comment: Actually the unknown thing is BladeInstance as it is not there in frame1 of MovieClip Player1Child(it comes to play in frame2 of Player1Child). Do I have any hopes? Thank you in advance.

Comment: this should be an easy fix. there's lots of similar posts on stackoverflow. You might be addressing the "stage" before the reference is given. Start your code with: 'addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);' and a handler for this listener 'private function init(e:Event):void
{
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    // write your code after this
}'  If you're framescripting (writing AS3 code in a frame) As the error stated - you're calling some objects property or method that is null. Your debugger will be able to point to the null object that you try to call on frame 2.

Comment: Really sorry but could you possible find out I have no clues, I added the link to the file in the description above. So sorry to bother you but thanks!